# org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: Bad address: Cannot bind

Tags: android, gradle

When I build my android project using `Gradle` in **`Android Studio 1.5`**, `Gradle` fails with this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Bad address: Cannot bind 
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: Bad address: Cannot bind
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:40)
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: 1.5? you realize that android is in 3.1 right now? please update your AS to 3.1